# Trying to access UINavigationController from within AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate, pushviewcontroller

Ok, I'm still pretty new to iOS development, so I apologize if this is a silly question.

But, I have an `AlertView` that I call from the `AppDelegate` then respond when clicking a button in the alert.  I can do a `NSLog` and see that the methods are getting called.  But, it's not pushing the view into the stack.  Here's a sample of what I have (I'm sure it's wrong):

This is in the `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ProfileConnection.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.    
return YES;
}

-(void)switchToController:(NSString *)controller animated:(BOOL)animated{

NSLog(@"switching to controller %@", controller);

// maybe we can do a check to see if a subview exists...and then push or pop accordingly.

// switch to the "TableView" view
if( [controller isEqualToString:@"ProfileConnection"]){
    NSLog(@"switching to the ProfileConnection view");

    ProfileConnection *profile = [[ProfileConnection alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileConnection" bundle:nil];
    [self.navController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];

}
}

-(void)showConnectionFoundAlert
{
NSString *connectFoundMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"We found someone we'd think you would like to meet:  Tony Davis"];
UIAlertView *connectionFoundAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Found" message:connectFoundMsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Decline" otherButtonTitles:@"Connect", @"View Profile", @"Save For Later", nil];
[connectionFoundAlert show];
//[connectionFoundAlert release];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
NSString *alertString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];

if([title isEqualToString:@"Decline"])
{
    alertString = @"Declied";
}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Connect"])
{
    alertString = @"Connected";
}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"View Profile"])
{
    //alertString = @"Profile Viewed";
    //NSLog(@"View Profile is being called");

    [self switchToController:@"ProfileConnection" animated:YES];

    //UIViewController *profile = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileConnection" bundle:nil];
    //ProfileConnection *profile = [[ProfileConnection alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileConnection" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    //[nav pushViewController:profile animated:NO];


    /*UIViewController *profile = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileConnection" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navigation pushViewController:profile animated:YES];*/

    /*
    ProfileConnection *profile = [ProfileConnection alloc];
    //UIView *current = self.window;
    [self.window addSubview:profile.view];
    */
    /*
    [window addSubview:view1.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    - (void)goToNextPage {
        view2 = [ViewController2 alloc];   
        UIView *current = self.window;
        [self.window addSubview:view2.view];
    */

}
else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Save For Later"])
{
    alertString = @"Saved It";
}

UIAlertView *alertStr = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:alertString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

if ([alertString isEqualToString:@""]) {

} else {
    [alertStr show];        
}
}

@end
```

This is the `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ProfileConnection.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIAlertViewDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UINavigationController *navController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;

-(void)showConnectionFoundAlert;
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
-(void)switchToController:(NSString *)controller animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

I am able to add the view with this, but I lose my navigation controller:

```
ProfileConnection *profile = [ProfileConnection alloc];
[self.window addSubview:profile.view];
```

You can see I have tried a few approaches, but I'm confusing myself trying to use the storyboard approach.

Also, the ProfileConnection view is blank with a single label at the moment, if that helps.

Comment: How do you create your navController?

Comment: please also show your ProfileConnection code.

Comment: Where is your third code snippet coming from. In your App Delegate the `pushViewController` is how you get something onto the stack.

Comment: The third snippet is a piece of code that worked (as in it actually put the view on top of the stack) but I lost my navigation controller.

Comment: The navigation controller is created in IB using the storyboard.  This is the first time I've tried using the storyboard, so I'm probably confusing myself trying to use it.

Comment: And I can tell that the method is being called with the NSLog(), but the view doesn't get pushed and I get no error.  =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks ok `[self.navController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];` is how you should do it.

You should make sure that you have added the navigation controller to the window.  Perhaps this should already be done by the storyboard, but if not user the [rootviewcontroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) property of the window (its better than `addSubview`).

```
self.window.rootViewContorller = self.navController;
```

Now do a sanity check to make sure nothing is nil (`profile` or the `navController`).

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@",self.navController, profile);
```

Does any of that help?

Comment: Ah yes ... self.navController is nil.  Does that mean I didn't link something up in the storyboard?  Thanks again for the help.  It's very appreciated!

Comment: This is the first time I've had this much trouble ... so I am thinking it has something to do with the storyboard (since this is the first time I've used the storyboard).  Just not sure what I'm missing.  Maybe linking something up in IB?  =\

Comment: Just for the record, I was able to get passed this issue by starting a new project and not using the storyboard.  Everything is working great now.  I guess I'm just not ready to start using storyboards.  =)